# Get ArrayList in xsl using xalan

Tags: java, validation, xslt, xalan

I have a page for adding data. And validator

```
<xsl:param name="validator"/>

<xsl:variable name="errorList" select="validator:getErrorList()" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$errorList">
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

When validation is failed. I return to the same page and want to get error list. Now I get error message that ArrayList cannot be cast to NodeList.

Comment: Can you modify the `validator.getErrorList()` method to return a `NodeList` or a result-tree fragment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm faced the same problem and i solved it by return `org.apache.xpath.NodeSet` instead of `ArrayList<String>` in java method . The XSLT and Java code are below

- Java Method

  ```
  public NodeSet getNodeSet(){     
  DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();  

  NodeSet nodeset =  new NodeSet();
  nodeset.addElement(doc.createTextNode("noteOne"));
  nodeset.addElement(doc.createTextNode("nodetTwo"));
  System.out.println("NodeSet length: " + nodeset.getLength());
     return nodeset;
   }
  ```
- XSLT Code

  ```
    <xsl:for-each select="myclass:getNodeSet()">
          <li>
              <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
  ```

I hope it can help